# I get ImportError when building a python app in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a python newb, and am trying to build a Github python app in VSCode, link here:
https://github.com/mapsme/osm_conflate

The devs aren't very responsive, and the problem is not very specific to the program, so I'm asking here. I made the launch.json file in the folder `/home/janko/source/osm_conflate/.vscode/`, the contents here:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/conflate/conflate.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/conflate/",
            "args": [
                "-p", "/home/janko/Documents/profile.py",
                "-o", "josm.osm"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I get an error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
  File "/home/janko/source/osm_conflate/conflate/conflate.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .geocoder import Geocoder
```

I tried to change the python version from 3 to python2, but the text of the error just changes a bit. I tried to put other folders in the `"cwd"` property, but it's always the same. I tried to put other .py files in the `"program"` part of the json, but it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need a file called literally `__init__.py` to indicate that the directory may be used as a library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 0):

From [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), we can know

> Relative imports use a module’s **name** attribute to determine that
> module’s position in the package hierarchy. If the module’s name does
> not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to **main** ) then
> relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level
> module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file
> system.

To solve the encountered error, we may use absolute import instead of relative import.

1. Change the folder conflate to other name, or else when you use `from conflate.geocoder import Geocoder` in conflate.py, it will throw a cirle import error.
2. Copy the content in `__init__.py` then delete it. Paste the content to a new created `__init__.py`, then reload the window;
3. Use `pip install lxml` to install the required module to the current environmet;
4. In conflate.py, add `sys.path.append('./')` and import functions like `from conflate.geocoder import Geocoder`.

Finally you can run conflate.py successfully:

[image]